# Update Project version automatically in Maven 3.6.0

Tags: java, maven-3

I am using Maven 3.6.0 in a project where the version of my project is set using a `revision` property as described in https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html and I want to automatically update the project's version in command line.

I tried to look on the side of `maven release plugin` (https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/update-versions-mojo.html) using the `release:update-versions` command, which seems to work, but instead of updating the property `revision` it updates the `version` property.

Current setup :

```html
    <version>${revision}</version>

    <properties>
        <revision>1.1-SNAPSHOT</revision>
    </properties>
```

When running `mvn release:update-versions` :

```xml
    <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <revision>1.1-SNAPSHOT</revision>
    </properties>
```

Expected:

```xml
    <version>${revision}</version>

    <properties>
        <revision>1.2-SNAPSHOT</revision>
    </properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the explanation why this is happening:

When `mvn release:update-versions` is executed then it will bump the version by first fetching value of revision property. This command does not care about updating property value as well.

In general, property value in maven can be updated using -D flag within command line as follows:

`mvn release -Drevision=1.2-SNAPSHOT`

Following links could also be helpful:

https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/non-interactive-release.html

https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/update-versions-mojo.html

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I achieved to get the same result by using maven `versions` plugin, but it's not using `${revision}` tag.

`mvn versions:set -DnextSnapshot=true`

Versions plugin is much more flexible than release plugin for managing your project's version.